# Update primary keys without creating duplicate rows?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hash

I'm working on a Java project which needs to be able to alter all the primary keys in a table - and in most cases - some other values in the row as well.
The problem I have is that, if I update a row by selecting by its old primary key (SET pk=new_pk WHERE pk=old_pk) I get duplicate rows (since the old PK value may be equal to another row's new PK value and both rows are then updated).

I figured that in Oracle and some other DBs I might be able to do this with ROWNUM or something similar, but the system should work with most DB systems and right now we can't get this to work for MySQL.

I should add that I don't have access to change the schema of the DB - so, I can't add a column.

What I have tried:

- Updating ResultSets directly with RS.updateRow() - this seems to
  work, but is very slow.
- Hashing the PK's in the table, storing the hash in code and selecting on the hashed PK. This acts sort of as a signature, since a
  hashed PK indicates that the row has been read but not yet updated
  and I can avoid appropriate rows that way. The issue with this seems
  to have been hash collisions as I was getting duplicate PKs.

**PS:**
I realise this sounds like either a terrible idea, or terrible design, but we really have no choice. The system I'm working on aims to anonymize private data and that may entail changing PKs in some tables. Don't fear, we do account for FK references.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Disble constraints, update and enable constraints

Comment: You shouldn't update Primary keys generated with a sequence asking for trouble with foreign keys

Comment: How often will you need to do this?  `Cuz I'm thinking if only once, just do it the slow way that works and be done with it.  Unless it's **really**  slow, like measured in weeks...

Comment: This sounds like a design fault, if your key is currently something meaningful (like an order number for example) then create a surrogate key, like an auto-increment value.  This will always be the same and you can update the other values as normal.

Comment: @NigelRen Although this is good design, the problem right now isn't so much in the design of the table, and more in the task we need to perform. Our objective is specifically to alter the PKs in an existing table (along with all the references). We unfortunately have no access apart from INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE.

Comment: @KevinAnderson, unfortunately relatively often - on different systems. It's a big part of the requirements for the system. I updated the question to shed some more light.

Comment: Why not solve the problem before it starts? Could you choose only new (anonymized) PKs that don't match any of the existing PKs?

Comment: @KevinAnderson In most cases that might be possible, but we run the risk of a key space which is too small to accommodate 2*n keys. Right now we're avoiding MySQL and PostgreSQL since neither have a unique ID that is automatically created (whereas Oracle has ROWID). Personally, I'm not convinced this is even solvable without us being allowed to alter the schema and maybe add an auto_ID column.

Comment: "unfortunately have not access..." -- Suggest you warm up your resume.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use simple update with delta = max Pk from updating table

select delta

```
select max(pk) as delta from table
```

and then use it in query

```
update table SET pk=pk+delta+1
```

Before this operation  you need to disable constraints. And don't forget that you should also update foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it may help. We may, however, end up having a problem with non-numeric or strictly limited PKs.